# PlotRange working only with some ListDensityPlots

Tags: plotting, visualization

I'm trying to compare simulated data to the recontruction of said data by a program I made after adding noise to the data. My original data is stored in a matrix called `dtest`, and the reconstructed data is stored in a matrix called `dsol`. In order to compare the two sets of data, I'm using `ListDensityPlot` with an attached `BarLegend`. To compare the two graphs more easily, I'd like them to have the same scale. However, `PlotRange` refuses to work on the graph of `dtest`. The code for the two graphs is identical with the exception of the data that is being graphed.

MWE showing that `PlotRange` doesn't work:

```
dtest=Table[4Floor[(j-1)/20],{j,1,100},{l,1,100}];
Table[
    Legended[
        ListDensityPlot[
            dtest,
            PlotRange->{0,max},
            ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
            FrameLabel->{Row[{x}],Row[{y}]}
        ],
        BarLegend[
            {"Rainbow",{0,max}},
            LegendLabel->Row[{d}]
        ]
    ],
    {max,16,20,1}
]
```

Here's the output:

[image]

As you can see, in the code both `PlotRange` and `BarLegend` go from 0 to whatever `max` is equal to, but only the `BarLegend` actually changes.

In the case of `dsol`, `PlotRange` does work:

```
Table[
    Legended[
        ListDensityPlot[
            dtest,
            PlotRange->{0,max},
            ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
            FrameLabel->{Row[{x}],Row[{y}]}
        ],
        BarLegend[
            {"Rainbow",{0,max}},
            LegendLabel->Row[{d}]
        ]
    ],
    {max,16,20,1}
]
```

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. If I change the value of a single element of dtest to something equal to or larger than 20, `PlotRange` works fine. If I change it to, say, 17, `PlotRange` works fine when `max` is 16 or 17 but not for larger values of `max`. It seems Mathematica is for some reason setting the upper bound of the plot range to `Min[max,Max[dtest]]` instead of `max`. It does the converse for the lower bound and `Min[dtest]`. It's annoying, but it's good to know that at least there's a simple workaround.

I won't accept my own answer in case someone comes up with a better workaround to this.